Android Media Pipe Filters
Is anyone working on any face image filters or third-party libraries using Google MediaPipe mesh points or open cv  for Android?Need to render the 2d or 3d image usig media pipe or open cv.

I have used a filter from a drawable image, but it was not dynamic.Please
